# How to remove keys with null values from Argonaut Json objects

Tags: scala, argonaut

How can an extension method be written to remove all keys with a `null` value from an Argonaut `Json` object:

I tried this:

```
package object Extensions {
  implicit class JsonExtensions(val json: Json) extends AnyVal {
    def removeNulls: Json = {
      json.withObject(j => JsonObject.from (j.toMap.filter(!_._2.isNull).toList))
    }
  }
}
```

but it only seems to be removing keys with `null` values at the top level of the `Json` object...

Comment: My understanding of that library is that you have to explicitly define how many levels of nesting you want the lenses to drill into.

Comment: You need to recurse into the nodes to do that.

Answer (score 6):

Argonaut supports this internally, you can use `PrettyParams` to do what you're after:

```
def removeNulls: Json = {
  json.pretty(PrettyParams.nospace.copy(dropNullKeys = true)).toJson
}
```

Hope this covers your question!